# PHP register_shutdown_function 1 second delay

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I'm trying to figure out why PHP takes 1 full second to execute a `register_shutdown_function`. And if there is a way to overcome this.

```
<?php

$start_time = microtime(true);

function shutdown($start_time)
{
    $time_diff = round(1000 * (microtime(true)-$start_time));
    echo $time_diff . "ms<br/>";
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $start_time);
register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $start_time);
register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $start_time);
register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $start_time);
register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $start_time);
```

Outputs:

```
1001ms
2001ms
3003ms
4003ms
5003ms
```

Running XAMPP 1.6.8 on Windows / PHP: 5.2.6

Comment: Doesn't happen for me: I get five "0ms" on 5.3.15.  What does an `strace` show you?

Comment: http://3v4l.org/ZGQ22

Comment: I'm running on with XAMPP 1.6.8 with Windows 7. Wondering if it's  windows specific.

Comment: Could be. If you disable all the dll loading in php.ini, do you get expected performance?

Comment: Looks like Xdebug was causing it. Anyone else want to test it to see if turning on xdebug causes the delay?

Comment: XDebug tracing will do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035565/php-profiling-delay-before-shutdown-function

Comment: There is a correct answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/19273025/341260

Comment: @barbushin It might be worth putting that link in an answer so it can be marked as correct and the question can be closed. Or is marking as a duplicate more appropriate even though the question is totally different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enabling xdebug remote debug makes apache server very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736304/enabling-xdebug-remote-debug-makes-apache-server-very-slow)